# OpenSSL Session Reuse not working with Safari

Tags: c, session, safari, openssl, reusability

Working on a C socket implementation using openssl I came across the problem, that Safari won't reuse SSL sessions to speed up connections. It is working just fine with Firefox and Chrome.

To reproduce the issue I'm opening the browser and point to IP:Port of the socket. Here are the relevant openssl methods I use to secure the socket, in order:

**Globally**

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
SSL_METHOD * meth = SSLv23_server_method();
sslInfo->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(sslInfo->ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_BOTH);
SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context(sslInfo->ctx, (void *)&ssl_session_ctx_id, sizeof(ssl_session_ctx_id));
SSL_CTX_set_generate_session_id(sslInfo->ctx, generateSslSession);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslInfo->ctx, "....pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslInfo->ctx, "....pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

**Per Connection**

```
cSSL = SSL_new(data->ctx);
ssl_err = SSL_accept(cSSL);
sslfderr = SSL_set_fd(cSSL, data->clientfd);
reused = SSL_session_reused(cSSL);
if(reused) {
    printf("Reused Session\n");
} else {
    printf("New Session\n");
}
SSL_read(cSSL, buf, (int) bufSize);
SSL_write(cSSL, msg, (int) strlen(msg));
SSL_free(cSSL);
close(clientfd);
```

Then connecting to the socket using a Safari browser gives the following output:

```
New Session
New Session
New Session
New Session
...
```

While using Firefox or Chrome gives the output as expected:

```
New Session
Reused Session
Reused Session
Reused Session
```

The question now is, if there is something special to consider for Safari regarding sessions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apple's ***`SecureTransport`*** supports session caching and reuse. See [Secure Transport Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/) and [Technical Q&A QA1727](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html). It sounds like its a Safari issue. *"...I'm opening the browser and point to IP:Port of the socket..."* - Apple uses ***`{destination IP address, destination port, destination DNS name}`*** as the index into the cache.

Comment: Safari supports it of course. I also can see that using Wireshark when connecting to an Apache Webserver. I will investigate on this and check why it's not working